# PHP base64 encode a pdf file

Tags: php, base64

I am using an API where I can send a document to something like dropbox.  According to the documentation, the file which is sent needs to be BASE64 encoded data.

As such, I am trying something like this

```
$b64Doc = chunk_split(base64_encode($this->pdfdoc));
```

Where `$this->pdfdoc` is the path to my PDF document.

At the moment, the file is being sent over but it seems invalid (displays nothing).

Am I correctly converting my PDF to BASE64 encoded data?

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`base64_encode` takes a string input. So all you're doing is encoding the path. You should grab the contents of the file

```
$b64Doc = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->pdfdoc)));
```

Comment: Why is chunk_split() need here?

Comment: @TrầnHữuHiền From the php docs: ``chunk_split()`` can be used to split a string into smaller chunks which is useful for e.g. converting base64_encode() output to match RFC 2045 semantics. It inserts separator every length characters.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Answer (score 6):

`base64_encode()` will encode whatever string you pass to it. If the value you pass is the file name, all you are going to get is an encoded filename, not the contents of the file.

You'll probably want to do `file_get_contents($this->pdfdoc)` or something first.

Answer (score 3):

**Convert base64 to pdf and save to server path.**

```
// Real date format (xxx-xx-xx)
$toDay   = date("Y-m-d");

// we give the file a random name
$name    = "archive_".$toDay."_XXXXX_.pdf";

// a route is created, (it must already be created in its repository(pdf)).
$rute    = "pdf/".$name;

// decode base64
$pdf_b64 = base64_decode($base_64);

// you record the file in existing folder
if(file_put_contents($rute, $pdf_b64)){
    //just to force download by the browser
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");

    //print base64 decoded
    echo $pdf_b64;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You're decoding, when the OP is about encoding