# PHP Base64 encoding for JSON slash issue

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch, base64

I am using [Elastic-PHP API 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/index.html) to create an index of Word and PDF documents. This normally requires to send a Base64 encoding of the document as JSON to its [Mapper attachment plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments).

However, PHP's Base64 generates slashes `\` in the encoded string. The JSON which I am trying to construct with this encoding, cannot be parsed by Elastic:

```
$json = 
    '{"content" : "'.addslashes(chunk_split(base64_encode($file_contents))).'"}'
```

I do not want to remove/replace the slashes, as [suggested in some Stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182379/php-base64-encode-a-pdf-file), since it may cause problems later with decoding.

How are slashes in Base64 encoding dealt with in such scenarios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better not to build the JSON string yourself, but to let [**json_encode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) do the job, which takes care of slashes. You don't need **addslashes** then:

```
// create the object
$obj = array(
    "content" => chunk_split(base64_encode($file_contents))
);
// encode the object in JSON format
$json = json_encode($obj);
```

Note that the new line characters that you insert with **chunk_split** will be escaped during the encoding, as JSON does not allow non-escaped line breaks in strings. If the receiving end decodes the JSON string in the right way, it will result in the value *$obj* has in the above code, with *content* having line breaks.

In an [Elastic blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-getting-started-with-lire-and-elasticsearch), the author even removes any line breaks in the base64 encoded string. The Scala code presented there has this:

> ```
> "image" :"${new BASE64Encoder().encode(data).replaceAll("[\n\r]", "")}"
> ```

This really seems to suggest you shouldn't be using **chunk_split** either, so then the suggested PHP code becomes:

```
// create the object
$obj = array(
    "content" => base64_encode($file_contents)
);
// encode the object in JSON format
$json = json_encode($obj);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use php function

addslashes() to add slash or any special character , to retrive slashes use stripslashes().

thanks...